# CUDA fft 2d different results from MATLAB fft on 2d

Tags: matlab, math, cuda, signal-processing, fft

I have tried to do a simple fft and compare the results between MATLAB and CUDA on 2d arrays.

MATLAB:
array of 9 numbers 1-9

```
I = [1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9];
```

and use this code:

```
fft(I)
```

gives the results:

```
 12.0000 + 0.0000i  15.0000 + 0.0000i  18.0000 + 0.0000i
  -4.5000 + 2.5981i  -4.5000 + 2.5981i  -4.5000 + 2.5981i
  -4.5000 - 2.5981i  -4.5000 - 2.5981i  -4.5000 - 2.5981i
```

And CUDA code:

```
int FFT_Test_Function() {

int width = 3;
int height = 3;
    int n = width * height;

double in[width][height];
Complex out[width][height];

for (int i = 0; i<width; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
    {
        in[i][j] = (i * width) + j + 1;
    }
}

    // Allocate the buffer
    cufftDoubleReal *d_in;
    cufftDoubleComplex *d_out;
    unsigned int out_mem_size = sizeof(cufftDoubleComplex)*n;
    unsigned int in_mem_size = sizeof(cufftDoubleReal)*n;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_in, in_mem_size);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_out, out_mem_size);

    // Save time stamp
    milliseconds timeStart = getCurrentTimeStamp();

    cufftHandle plan;
    cufftResult res = cufftPlan2d(&plan, width, height, CUFFT_D2Z);
    if (res != CUFFT_SUCCESS) { cout << "cufft plan error: " << res << endl; return 1; }
    cudaCheckErrors("cuda malloc fail");

for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
{
    cudaMemcpy(d_in + (i * width), &in[i], height * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaCheckErrors("cuda memcpy H2D fail");
}
    cudaCheckErrors("cuda memcpy H2D fail");

    res = cufftExecD2Z(plan, d_in, d_out);
    if (res != CUFFT_SUCCESS) { cout << "cufft exec error: " << res << endl; return 1; }
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
{
    cudaMemcpy(&out[i], d_out + (i * width), height * sizeof(Complex), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaCheckErrors("cuda memcpy H2D fail");
}
    cudaCheckErrors("cuda memcpy D2H fail");

    milliseconds timeEnd = getCurrentTimeStamp();
    milliseconds totalTime = timeEnd - timeStart;
    std::cout << "Total time: " << totalTime.count() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In this CUDA code i got the result:

[image]
You can see that CUDA gives different results.

What am i missed?

Thank you very much for your attention!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cuFFT result looks correct, but your FFT code is wrong - it should be:

```
octave:1> I = [ 1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9 ]
I =

   1   2   3
   4   5   6
   7   8   9

octave:2> fft2(I)
ans =

   45.00000 +  0.00000i   -4.50000 +  2.59808i   -4.50000 -  2.59808i
  -13.50000 +  7.79423i    0.00000 +  0.00000i    0.00000 +  0.00000i
  -13.50000 -  7.79423i    0.00000 -  0.00000i    0.00000 -  0.00000i
```

Note the use of [`fft2`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft2.html).

Comment: I have a matlab code and i need to convert it to cuda code.
In matlab code they used fft and not fft2:
"picFFT = fft(I, size(I,3), 3);"
Where I is a matrix 1024x1024x69
So i need to do the same in cuda. Please advice.

Comment: If you have a different question about 3D FFTs then feel free to post it as a new question. You might also want to spend a little time reading up on FFTs and MATLAB in general, since it will be more efficient in the long than posting multiple related questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you paul for your help. But please try to be specific.
fft2 is fft(fft(X)).
But ff2 is not the function that i need. In my exist matlab code (I can not change it) there a use of fft and not fft2.
So, i need to do the same in my CUDA code. fft of matrix is fft of each vector am i right? so CUDA 'cufftPlan2d' function not do the same? i need to launch 69x1024 kernels and use cufftPlan1d ?!
Thank you again!

Comment: You wil first need to understand what your MATLAB code does. MATLAB's `fft` applied to a matrix is *not* the same thing as a 2D FFT. A 2D FFT is an FFT of each row followed by an FFT of each column (which is what `fft2` does). That is why I said above that you probably ought to read up a bit on FFTs and MATLAB, otherwise you are going to be constantly tripping up on these fundamental misunderstandings.

Comment: OK Paul thank you about your excellent help.  I have not enough reputation So i cant hit on + on your answers:)

Comment: You're welcome - don't worry about the rep - it's not important.

Comment: I'm happy to do so.  Well done, Paul.  An insightful answer.

Comment: @duffymo: Thanks. :-)